# how to make same instance as new instance to top of the stack when same instance is running in android

Tags: java, android

Here the group chat activity is running currently. **Group chat activity** means chat window. in that chat window i retrieved the message from `sqlite` and showed by `list view adpater`. Here i am doing group chat for one event when new message is arrived for other event the notification issued. When i click the notification my group chat activity is not executed again even if i **passed the intent** from other class or activity.

This is my `groupchatActivity` code

```
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (activeEventMO != null) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("APPSTATUS", 1);
            editor.putLong("eventId", activeEventMO.getEventId());
            editor.commit();
            Log.i("App", "start");
            AppActivityStatus.setActivityStarted();
            AppActivityStatus.setActivityContext(context);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStoped();

    }


    protected  void onNewIntent(Intent intent){

        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        processExtraData();

    }

    private void processExtraData() {
        activeEventMO = (EventMO) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("eventMo");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onPause();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStarted();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i("App", "stop");
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("APPSTATUS", 2);
        editor.commit();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStoped();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.image_upload, menu);
        return true;
    }
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final List<ChatMO> chatMOs1 = new ArrayList<>();
        setContentView(R.layout.chat_main);
        EventMO eventMO = new EventMO();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        listChatMessageObjectses = chatMOs1;
        inputMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputMsg);
        listViewMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_messages);
        //this activeEventMO is a static object
        processExtraData();
       // activeEventMO = (EventMO) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("eventMo");
         List<ChatMO> chatMOs = dbHelper.getGroupChatMessageForEvent(activeEventMO.getEventId());
        //this for loop is for avoiding the notification coz notification also stores groupchat table in sqlite
        for (ChatMO chatMO1 : chatMOs) {
            chatMO1.getMessage();
            chatMO1.getEvent_id();
            chatMO1.getFromName();
            int messageType = chatMO1.getMessage_type();
            chatMO1.getDate();
            chatMO1.isSelf();
            if (messageType == 0) {
                chatMOs1.add(chatMO1);
            }

        }


        adapter = new MessagesListAdapter(context, chatMOs1);

        //adapter functionality added for show the previous chat list of event/invite
        listViewMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // by default first primary user is current user in sql lite
        // user table
        userMO = dbHelper.getUserData(1);


       /* if (!sharedpreferences.getString("MessageMO", "null").equals("null")) {
            MessageMO messageMO1 = (MessageMO) gson.fromJson(sharedpreferences.getString("MessageMO", "null"), new TypeToken<MessageMO>() {
            }.getType());
            eventMO.setEventId(messageMO1.getEventId());
            Log.e("shared","eventID"+messageMO1.getEventId());
            Log.e("shared","eventID"+eventMO.getEventId());
            eventMO.setText(messageMO1.getEventTitle());
            Log.i("message values", messageMO1.toString());
            ChatMO chatMO = new ChatMO();
            //chatMessageObjects.setMessage(messageMO1.getMessage());
            chatMO.setSelf(0);
            chatMO.setFromName(messageMO1.getfromUserName());
            listChatMessageObjectses.add(chatMO);
            //listViewMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }*/

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                return userDelegate.getUsersForEvent(activeEventMO.getEventId());
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String eventLists) {
                eventUserMOs = gson.fromJson(eventLists, new TypeToken<ArrayList<UserMO>>() {
                }.getType());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "event users " + eventUserMOs.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
        Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
```

This `gcmIntent` here i am passing the intent from this `gcmIntent`

```
Intent groupChatActFrag = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GroupChatActivity.class);
            EventMO eventMO = new EventMO();
            //here messageMO having the details of received message here i am setting eventId from messageMO to eventMO
            // Inorder to passs gropchatActivity
            eventMO.setEventId(messageMO.getEventId());
            groupChatActFrag.putExtra("eventMo", eventMO);
            groupChatActFrag.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("MessageMO", gson.toJson(messageMO));
            editor.commit();
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, groupChatActFrag, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog_info).setContentTitle(messageMO.getEventTitle())
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageMO.getfromUserName())).setContentText(messageMO.getMessage()).setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

            mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            mNotificationManager.notify((int) (long) messageMO.getEventId(), mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do couple of things to achieve the result.

1. Set launch mode of groupchatactivity to SingleTask
2. Override onNewIntent() method in groupchatactivity
3. Call setIntent(intent) for new received intent in onNewIntent()

Reflect as appropriate on above answer.

Comment: can  u pls explain how to setIntent for recived intent in onNewIntent. here i am using parcelable to pass an object and retrive the object

Comment: just put the call setIntent(intent); just before your call processExtraData(); in onNewIntent(). This should work. Reflect as appropriate.

Comment: still i got the same problem here activeEventMO is a static object . my received activity not started when i click the notification